# Copy/paste multibyte string from gzdeflate?

Tags: php, multibyte

Take the output of `gzdeflate()`, for example:

```
$a = gzdeflate('..........');
echo $a . "\n" . strlen($a);
```

I get output like:

```
?Ӄ
5
```

So I've got a 5 byte string that contains characters which cannot be outputted properly, and hence cannot be copy and pasted.

Obviously, `echo gzinflate('?Ӄ');` doesn't work, but `echo gzinflate($a)` does.

Is there any way to get the actual contents of `$a` onto my clipboard or output it in such a way that I could copy and paste it into `gzinflate()` to retrieve the original string?  The only workaround I've found is something like:

```
$a = base64_encode(gzdeflate('..........'));
echo $a;
```

Which gives me:

```
09ODAQA=
```

That's friendly enough to do `echo gzinflate(base64_decode('09ODAQA='));` and get `..........`, but I'd like to skip the base64 functions if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're channeling binary data through a text medium. If you require the data to be printed out on your screen where you will select and copy it, there's no way to transport binary data like that.

If this is happening on the command line, you *could* do it programatically without displaying the actual contents. Take OS X's `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` commands:

```
$ php test.php | pbcopy
$ pbpaste | someotherprogram
```

If you do require a *visible textual representation*, you need to ensure that the output is ASCII-safe (or at least "Unicode safe") and not raw binary data. For that you will need to base 64 or hex encode your binary data.

Comment: Thanks - yes a visible textual representation is what I'm after - do you know of any way to get output like that directly from ***any*** compression functions without using a second encoding function? It doesn't necessarily have to be `gzdeflate()`

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of such a compression function, really.

Comment: not necessarily.  The output here is 5 bytes while the original string is 10.  Essentially I'm looking for a useable textual representation that is still only 5 bytes.

Comment: Your *usable textual representation* in this case has *8* bytes; the 5 byte variant is the unusable one. While it is certainly possible to have a compression function which takes ASCII-safe values and compresses to ASCII-safe output, I am not aware of such an implementation. Why is that required? Are your values too large to compress and then encode in two separate steps?

Comment: Not at all, I just got curious about the mechanics of compression and whether or not something like this already exists.  Thanks for answering my question and for the interesting articles linked in your profile which I am currently digesting.  cheers

Answer (score 0):

I guess your browser or console just eat some special chars like break line and other.

You can put this string to any file (file_put_contents()), and open this file throw notepad++ for example. and you will see these special chars in this file.

Comment: Not really... tried this in sublime and got `d3d3 8301 00` which I'm assuming is hex code and cannot be inflated as is

Comment: Yes, you can see it is 5 bytes and system just eat this char -  ___00___